# How to get Coefficients of polynomial of degree n mod p?

Tags: algorithm, math, wolfram-mathematica, modulo, polynomials

**F(x) = a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>x + a<sub>2</sub>x<sup>2</sup> + . . . + a<sub>n</sub>x<sup>n</sup>** is a polynomial function of degree n, there are sufficient methods for finding the coefficients of polynomial equation F(x). (i.e. finding values of a<sub>0</sub> , a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, . . . a<sub>n</sub>)

 
However, I was wondering on how to get coefficients of equation **F(x) = (a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>x + a<sub>2</sub>x<sup>2</sup> + . . . + a<sub>n</sub>x<sup>n</sup>) % p**. Where p is a prime number.  
 
For example, consider the equation 
 F(x) = (a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>x + a<sub>2</sub>x<sup>2</sup>) % p
 Let a<sub>0</sub> = 5, a<sub>1</sub> = 3 and a<sub>3</sub> = 2,
 and **P = 71** then **F(10) = 22**, **F(20) = 13**, **F(30) = 49** for x = 10, 20, 30.
Is there any way to find the **same coefficients of F(x)** (i.e. a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub> and a<sub>2</sub>) from the data
 **P(=71)** ,**F(10)**, **F(20)**, **F(30)** for x = 10, 20, 30 ?

Comment: If this is a question about *Mathematica* show us your code and we'll help you correct it.

Comment: You have 3 linear equations, which you can solve in the usual ways (eg by gaussian elimination).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it as a set of linear equations. For addition subtraction and multiplication, perform operations modulo n. For dividing, multiply with the multiplicative inverse. Take the example given in the question. The equations become:

(All calculated on mod 71)

```
1. a0 + 10a1 + 29a2 == 22 
2. a0 + 20a1 + 45a2 == 13 
3. a0 + 30a1 + 48a2 == 49
```

Subtract equations 1 from 2

```
4. 10a1 + 16a2 == 62
```

Subtract equations 2 from 3

```
5. 10a1 + 3a2 == 36
```

Subtract 5 from 4 to get

```
13a2 == 26
=>a2 == 26/13 == 26*11 == 2
```

The same methods that are applied to general polynomials can be modified. For instance, we can use a matrix to solve the set of linear equations programmatically.

Comment: after solving equations we get a0, a1, and a2. But why their values differ? (i.e. if we calculate f(10), f(20) and f(30) then their values differ from original values )

Comment: @GyaneshGunjan Sorry. There was a calculation mistake. I fixed it. 
The correct values are {a0,a1,a2} = {5,3,2}